# Retornar únicamente un valor en específico

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando retornar únicamente el valor “id”, les anexo que es json que estoy obtenido como respuesta y en el cual está el valor “id”:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "Proveedor_Celulares":[

         ],
         "Owner":{
            "name":"Roman Retana Espinosa",
            "id":"54017000025581001",
            "email":"rretana@abacom.mx"
         },
         "$state":"save",
         "$process_flow":false,
         "Currency":"MXN",
         "Billing_Country":null,
         "id":"54017000030118050",
         "Inv_Extranjero":null,
         "Inv_Nacional":null,
         "Proveedor_de_Internet":null,
         "Status":"Activa",
         "Sucursales":null,
         "Telulares_Si_o_No":null,
         "$approval":{
            "delegate":false,
            "approve":false,
            "reject":false,
            "resubmit":false
         },
         "Created_Time":"2019-10-18T10:02:01-05:00",
         "Lineas_contratadas":null,
         "Shipping_Country":"MÃ©xico",
         "Shipping_Code":"76230",
         "Billing_City":null,
         "Nacionalidad":"Mexicana",
         "Email_Contacto_Finanzas":"viridiana@bakerpartsbakeryequipment.com",
         "Created_By":{
            "name":"Roman Retana Espinosa",
            "id":"54017000025581001",
            "email":"rretana@abacom.mx"
         },
         "Annual_Revenue":null,
         "Contacto_Facturaci_n":null,
         "Shipping_Street":"Parcela 14 Z-1 Ejido Guadalupe la venta",
         "Description":null,
         "Apoderado_Legal":null,
         "Shipping_State":"QuerÃ©taro",
         "Colonia_de_facturaci_n":null,
         "$review_process":{
            "approve":false,
            "reject":false,
            "resubmit":false
         },
         "Website":null,
         "Razon_social_de_facturaci_n_1":"Baker Parts International S de RL de CV",
         "Record_Image":"8ac0f4534430d4cdbb88997b8b8c9249012f665fbb6e50a8ea37e6c7b8e006f0594baf9ac74559fedf38168e7e1cdf5e4b1c4eae81e05a8fcb40149e9abbb9e5d4f0cddbc2b971bbd1e361cdb93668a3",
         "Numero_de_Acta_para_Poder_Notarial":null,
         "Contacto_Finanzas":"Viridiana Fuentes",
         "Account_Name":"Baker Parts International S de RL de CV",
         "Clave_Campa_a":null,
         "Ancho_de_Banda_actual_Mb":null,
         "Pa_s_de_Origen":"MÃ©xico (MEX)",
         "BW_solicitado":"2Mb a 4Mb",
         "$orchestration":false,
         "DID_s":null,
         "Numero_de_Registro_P_blico_de_Comercio":null,
         "Tag":[

         ],
         "Calificado":false,
         "$currency_symbol":"MX$",
         "Interes":null,
         "A_o_Inicio_Opers":null,
         "Gasto_Celulares":null,
         "Account_Type":"Cliente",
         "$followers":null,
         "Colonia_de_envio":"San Isidro El MarquÃ©s",
         "RFC":"BPI190110BD2",
         "Last_Activity_Time":"2020-04-08T10:47:43-05:00",
         "Industry":"Industria Manufactura",
         "ID_CDR":2763,
         "Conmutador":null,
         "Exchange_Rate":1,
         "Nombre_corto_empresa":"Baker Parts International",
         "Contacto_de_Compras":null,
         "$approved":true,
         "ZONA_INDUSTRIAL":"TODOS EN QRO.",
         "Asociada_de_Ventas":null,
         "Otro_Proveedor_Internet":null,
         "Billing_Street":null,
         "Lineas_Telefonicas":null,
         "$followed":false,
         "$editable":true,
         "Billing_Code":null,
         "Email_Contacto_IT":"viridiana@bakerpartsbakeryequipment.com",
         "Shipping_City":"QuerÃ©taro",
         "Usuarios_Conectados":"De 1 a 10 usuarios",
         "Nombre_del_Notario":null,
         "Fecha_de_Acta_Constitutiva":null,
         "No_de_Registro_de_Identidad_Fiscal":null,
         "Ciudad_requiere_servicio":"QuerÃ©taro",
         "Ownership":null,
         "Cuantas_extensiones":null,
         "Rating":null,
         "Employees":null,
         "Maneja_Sucursales":true,
         "Modified_By":{
            "name":"Juan Carlos De la Torre Ayala",
            "id":"54017000000031001",
            "email":"jtorre@abacom.mx"
         },
         "$review":null,
         "Residencia_Fiscal":null,
         "Phone":"55 1350 7935",
         "Proveedor_Telefonia":[
            "Abasel"
         ],
         "No_PCs":null,
         "Modified_Time":"2020-04-08T10:47:43-05:00",
         "Gasto_Internet":null,
         "Email_Contacto_Facturaci_n":"viridiana@bakerpartsbakeryequipment.com",
         "Numero_de_Acta_Constitutiva":null,
         "No_de_Celulares":null,
         "Gasto_Telefonico":null,
         "Parent_Account":null,
         "Ancho_de_banda_requerido_Mb":null,
         "Billing_State":null,
         "EMail_Contacto_Compras":null
      }
   ],
   "info":{
      "per_page":200,
      "count":1,
      "page":1,
      "more_records":false
   }
}
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias.

Comment: te comprato mi codigo  $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response === false)
    {
        print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    print_r($response);

Comment: imprimi $response y obtengo los datos que publique pero no se como obtener unicamente el "id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basandome en la [Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/sdo.sample.getset.php) oficial, para acceder a las propiedades de un json, primero hay que tener el json decodificado, si tu `response` es de tipo String, crearías una variable para almacenar tu el json decodificado, y accederías a sus propiedades mas internas con la notacion `->`, algo como:

```php
$info = json_decode($response);
echo $info->data[0]->Owner->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes el valor retorno en jquery o  fetch solo puede asignar

```
 var  valor = data['id'];
```

Comment: print_r($response); en $response tengo los datos que se muestran arriba, ahora como accedo al "id"

Comment: estoy utilizando PHP no javascript